# UWP timer based on system time

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I am looking for a way to have an "alarm" type timer that throws an event at a specific system time. Is there a way to do this with UWP apps? I need my application to be able to enter "day mode" at a certain time in the day. Currently, I am using a System.Timers.Timer(), but if the computer goes into sleep mode in the middle of the timer running, it does not count sleep-mode time as part of the timed event. Is there a way to have an alarm type event that is based off of system time as opposed to "timed" time?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have an alarm type event that is based off of system time as opposed to "timed" time?

I have to say that the answer is no. There is no such way that could make an alarm still function in sleep mode. Even the system build-in Alarm app won't work in sleep mode.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The question isn't about creating a timer that fires during sleep mode. It's a timer that counts sleep time towards elapsed time. You can do this with a time-based background trigger, or you can do it in-app by creating an absolute waitable timer or an absolute threadpool timer. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a readily-available C# wrapper for CreateWaitableTimer or CreateThreadpoolTimer, so you'll have to p/invoke. But another way (probably easier) to do it is to respond to the Resume event and recalculate the timer on resume.